# can not run springboot junit tests with globally quoted identifiers

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase, hsqldb

I've got an app that runs with `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true`. The database changes are managed through liquibase and the app uses a mysql database.
The problem is that when I try and run my junit tests, which use a hsqldb, I get the following exception when a repository call is made:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token:  in statement
```

I believe this is because we're not currently setting a default schema, so it's running it without a schema but the liquibase created the tables in `PUBLIC` schema. I tried setting `spring.liquibase.default-schema=SCHEMA` in my test properties to be the same schema as my prod properties, but then liquibase gets

```
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: invalid schema name: SCHEMA in statement [CREATE TABLE SCHEMA.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
```

Because the schema hasn't been created yet in the HSQLDB.

Adding:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.schema=classpath:test-schema.sql
```

where `test-schema.sql` is just `CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS schema;` got me a bit further, but now when the tests run it tries to run some of the liquibase which runs a sql insert that is like `INSERT INTO table` without a schema attached, which fails. Unfortunately this changeset has already run against the actual app, so I can't really change it.

Is there a way to get `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true` along with setting the schema to work without getting rid of those changesets, or are the tests just totally hooped? Is there a way to get liquibase to run sql statements and automatically use the default schema for them?

If it helps, here is what my application-test.properties looks like:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb;
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
spring.liquibase.url=${spring.datasource.url}
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-test.xml
spring.liquibase.user=sa
spring.liquibase.contexts=test
spring.liquibase.password=

spring.liquibase.default-schema=schema
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.schema=classpath:test-schema.sql
```

Comment: Instead of `default-schema` can you try using property `spring.liquibase.liquibase-schema` once and check if liquibase creates the required objects in the specified schema.

Comment: Unfortunately even with the liquibase-schema property, when it goes to run the sql INSERT it still gives me: Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: user lacks privilege or object not found: TEST_TABLE [Failed SQL: (-5501) INSERT INTO test_table